# cakephp 3 + date convert from dd/mm/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I convert date which is in dd/mm/yy format to sql insert date format.

I tried

```
$time =  new \DateTime('d/m/y H:i', $this->request->data['date_from']);
pr($time);
```

getting error.

> DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeZone, string
>   given

When I try

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i', $str)->format('Y-m-d')
```

> Error: Class 'App\Controller\DateTime' not found

How can I do that

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)... either `$time =  new \DateTime($this->request->data['date_from'])->format('d/m/y H:i');` or `\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y H:i', $str)->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: @MarkBaker:  DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (28/12/16) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character

Comment: Then consider format of your `$this->request->data['date_from']` string... if it's not in one of PHP's recognised formats (and `28/12/16` isn't one of the recognised formats, because `/` separator indicates US format which is `m/d/Y`, and there is no month 28 in any year) then use `createFromFormat()`.... this is all documented in the PHP Docs

Answer (score 0):

this works for me `$myDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->request->data['date_from']))`

Comment: This is on pure PHP, can be done but the best is to use CakePHP code style.

Answer (score 0):

For **Cakephp 3.2** and above:

```
use Cake\I18n\Date;

$date = new Date($this->request->data['date_from']);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Reference**: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#dates